Question in the proof of the Riesz Representation theorem of non-negative functionals in geometric measure theory written by Leon Simon
The problem is from the proof of Theorem 1.5.12 in Leon Simon's book: Geometric Measure Theory

Suppose $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, $\mathcal{K}^{+}$ is the set of all non-negative continuous functions on $X$ with compact support, $\lambda:\mathcal{K}^{+}\to [0,\infty)$ is linear. $U$ open in $X$, $K$ compact in $X$, $A\subset X$. we define
$$\mu(U)=\sup\{\lambda(f):f\in\mathcal{K}^{+},f\leq 1,supp(f)\subset U\}$$
$$\mu(A)=\inf\{\mu(U):U\mbox{ open},U\supset A\}$$
Prove that $\mu(U) = \sup\{\mu(K):K\mbox{ compact}$, $K\subset U\}$.

In Leon Simon's book, the proof of this statement is too short to understand, so I was looking for clearer and more rigorous proof. Obviously LHS $\geq$ RHS, however I cannot prove the equality. Any help will be appreciated.

What exactly are you looking for? The statement of your theorem is proved in the book right after being introduced. Is something in the book's proof not clear to you? Your question doesn't make this clear.

In the book,  he said "(**), definition (1),(2) evidently imply" the first statement I want to show, but I didn't get why these arguments imply the result I want. Thank you for mentioning me.

Maybe the first one is clear to me now, but I can't prove the second one.

Given $U$, fix $\varepsilon>0$ and take $f\in \mathcal K^+$ with support (call it $K$) contained in $U$ and $f\le 1$ such that $\lambda(f)>\mu(U)-\varepsilon$
(such $f$ exists by definition of $\mu(U)$). Notice that $f$ is admissible for any open set containing $K$, hence
$$\mu(K)=\inf_{A\supset K\ \text{open}} \mu(A)\ge \lambda(f)>\mu(U)-\varepsilon\ge \inf_{A\supset K\ \text{open}} \mu(A)-\varepsilon=\mu(K)-\varepsilon.$$
Hence
$$\sup_{K\subset U\text{ compact}}\mu(K)\le \mu(U)\le \sup_{K\subset U\text{ compact}}\mu(K)+\varepsilon.$$
Take $\varepsilon\to 0$ and we get the theorem.

@OneLamp When I say that $f$ is admissible for $A$ it means that the support of $f$ is contained in $A$, hence it is contained in the set ${f\in\mathcal K^+, f\le 1, \text{supp}(f)\subset A}$ and thus $\mu(A)\ge \lambda(f)$

Thank you very much. I deleted the comment because I didn't see $K=$ support $f$. I thought $K$ is an arbitrary compact set.
